# Exception while running JRULES

Tags: jrules, ibm-odm

When i'm running the rules in ODM 8.8 getting the below exception. I am using the Decision engine 1.40

execution     E   It was not possible to create the ruleset: /MisApp/1.0/Mis/1.74.
                                 com.ibm.rules.res.xu.internal.XUException: GBRXU0467E: The creation of EngineDefinition failed.
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.engine.de.internal.XUEngineDynamicDefinitionFactory.createEngineDefinition(XUEngineDynamicDefinitionFactory.java:89)
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.ruleset.internal.XURulesetFactory.createDERuleset(XURulesetFactory.java:250)
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.ruleset.internal.XURulesetFactory.createRuleset(XURulesetFactory.java:117)
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.ruleset.internal.RulesetParsingWork.run(RulesetParsingWork.java:89)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy$RunWork.run(WorkProxy.java:282)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:422)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:494)
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:133)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy$RunWork.run(WorkProxy.java:285)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:667)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoader$CreationException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ibm.rules.generated.ruleflow.RuleflowDefinitionImpl.([Lcom.ibm.rules.engine.service.EngineService;)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.loadJar(XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.java:213)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.createEngineDefinitionFromDSAR(XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.java:77)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.createEngineDefinition(XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.java:52)
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.engine.de.internal.XUEngineDynamicDefinitionFactory.createEngineDefinition(XUEngineDynamicDefinitionFactory.java:82)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ibm.rules.generated.ruleflow.RuleflowDefinitionImpl.([Lcom.ibm.rules.engine.service.EngineService;)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:456)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.util.platform.JavaReflectionUtils.loadClassAndCreatesInstance(JavaReflectionUtils.java:103)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.load.NativeEngineLoader.createEngineDefinition(NativeEngineLoader.java:184)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.load.NativeEngineLoader.loadEngineFromJarStream(NativeEngineLoader.java:166)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.loadJar(XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.java:211)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ibm.rules.generated.ruleflow.RuleflowDefinitionImpl.([Lcom.ibm.rules.engine.service.EngineService;)
        at java.lang.Class.throwNoSuchMethodException(Class.java:461)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:521)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.util.platform.JavaReflectionUtils$3.run(JavaReflectionUtils.java:121)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:452)
        ... 18 more

[12/13/17 23:33:38:198 CST] 000001e4 execution     E   The interaction getXURulesetArchiveInformation has failed.
                                 com.ibm.rules.res.xu.internal.XUException: GBRXU0467E: The creation of EngineDefinition failed.
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.engine.de.internal.XUEngineDynamicDefinitionFactory.createEngineDefinition(XUEngineDynamicDefinitionFactory.java:89)
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.ruleset.internal.XURulesetFactory.createDERuleset(XURulesetFactory.java:250)
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.ruleset.internal.XURulesetFactory.createRuleset(XURulesetFactory.java:117)
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.ruleset.internal.RulesetParsingWork.run(RulesetParsingWork.java:89)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy$RunWork.run(WorkProxy.java:282)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:422)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:494)
        at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:133)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy$RunWork.run(WorkProxy.java:285)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
        at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:667)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoader$CreationException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ibm.rules.generated.ruleflow.RuleflowDefinitionImpl.([Lcom.ibm.rules.engine.service.EngineService;)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.loadJar(XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.java:213)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.createEngineDefinitionFromDSAR(XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.java:77)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.createEngineDefinition(XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.java:52)
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.engine.de.internal.XUEngineDynamicDefinitionFactory.createEngineDefinition(XUEngineDynamicDefinitionFactory.java:82)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ibm.rules.generated.ruleflow.RuleflowDefinitionImpl.([Lcom.ibm.rules.engine.service.EngineService;)

Comment: IBM doesn't seem to know the answer either ;-) https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.8.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.ref.res/html/extensions/html/GBRXU0016E.html

Do you have more context what you try to do? On what rules does it fail?

Comment: nope.. i deploy the rules into the rule execution server and when i try to run i am getting the above error. Any idea on why this error occurs

Comment: Is this complete error stack....  Also.. have you recently migrated to another version of ODM? Most of the time version mismatch cause the issue, so please ensure that as well.

Comment: Yeah , Mostly it'll we due to version mismatch. if you've migrated from lower version and tried to invoke the Decision service which is build and deployed in earlier version. this issue will occur. Try Building the workspace in latest Rule Designer Version and deploy it.

Comment: @GouseMoinuddinShaik can you explain a little bit more on the invoking decision Service which is build and deployed in earlier version please

Comment: @AmanChhabra i have added the complete error stack trace

Comment: @raghulc As it says Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ibm.rules.generated.ruleflow.RuleflowDefinitionImpl. It seems more to be a version mismatch issue please ensure your decision server is compatible with the version of ODM.

Comment: @AmanChhabra can you please let me know how to look at this, as i not sure where to go and look

Comment: @raghulc Can you please share history on this before I can further help you on this. Like have these rules ever worked? Are these rule working now on classic rule engine? Also, in decision engine dsar needs to be loaded instead of jar. Have you taken care of all these things? May be you can also refer IBM support page: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSQP76_8.8.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/executing_decision_topics/con_decision_engine.html

Comment: @AmanChhabra yes the rules were working and we are using the decision engine not the classic rule engine. All of a sudden the error message that i have pasted in the question started to occur. Finding it difficult to know the reason As previously when i deployed the rules to the rule execution server there was no issue

Comment: @raghulc As it is difficult to investigate such issues, try it from the beginning and let me know till what step you are able to proceed as mentioned in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSQP76_8.8.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/executing_decision_topics/con_decision_engine.html

Comment: @raghulc Also, as you have separately mentioned the decision engine version. Are you using different from the one that comes as a package with ODM 8.8.0

Comment: @AmanChhabra nope i'm not using a seperate one